# How to know if the processor is 64bit capable or not?

Tags: kubuntu, central-processing-unit

Is there any straight forward say ?

I am running the 32bit version of Kubuntu.

Here is my cpuinfo.

```
processor       : 0
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 6
model           : 15
model name      : Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     E6550  @ 2.33GHz
stepping        : 11
cpu MHz         : 2000.000
cache size      : 4096 KB
physical id     : 0
siblings        : 2
core id         : 0
cpu cores       : 2
fdiv_bug        : no
hlt_bug         : no
f00f_bug        : no
coma_bug        : no
fpu             : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level     : 10
wp              : yes
flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe nx lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts pni monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr lahf_lm
bogomips        : 4655.09
clflush size    : 64

processor       : 1
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 6
model           : 15
model name      : Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     E6550  @ 2.33GHz
stepping        : 11
cpu MHz         : 2000.000
cache size      : 4096 KB
physical id     : 0
siblings        : 2
core id         : 1
cpu cores       : 2
fdiv_bug        : no
hlt_bug         : no
f00f_bug        : no
coma_bug        : no
fpu             : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level     : 10
wp              : yes
flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe nx lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts pni monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr lahf_lm
bogomips        : 4655.00
clflush size    : 64
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `lm` flag indicates support for x86-64.

For comparison, the flags of an older Intel Xeon:

> flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc
>   msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca
>   cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx
>   fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe pebs bts
>   cid xtpr

Answer (score 3):

Flag 'lm' -- long mode